# Error "availableHeight is indefinite so heightMeasureMode must be YGMeasureModeUndefined" in APK Build in React Native

Tags: android, apk, react-native

I'm developing a React Native Android app which works fine when built using the command

```
react-native run-android
```

. However, when I install the app using the generated APK, I randomly get this error throughout the app:

```
A/yoga: availableHeight is indefinite so heightMeasureMode must be YGMeasureModeUndefined
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 10495 (mqt_native_modu)
```

This is replicated throughout different devices and Android versions. Note that when this error occurs, the app simply terminates without any logs aside these two lines in logcat (none in RN debugger, etc.). Worse, there's also no crash report generated for analytics so it's inconvenient to deploy the app with this rogue issue.

Based on the following links, this issue has been up since RN 0.30 and still occurring at RN 0.56:

- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9550
- https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19719

Unfortunately, there's been not much reports and there seems to be no clear solution for this one. In our case, downgrading from 0.55 to 0.49 doesn't sound a good option. Anyone encountered the same issue?

To add: I'm also using react-native-navigation among few other libraries

Comment: why not upgrade from 0.55 to 0.57 if the issue was fixed in 56?

Comment: Thanks. It's also reported that it's still not working in 0.56 and the RN developers didn't close the issue as fix for the latest version. It's worth a try upgrading.

Comment: Hi all..anyone solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error Error "availableWidth is indefinite so widthMeasureMode must be YGMeasureModeUndefined". In my case, I had a scroll view with the horizontal property true. I fix the error by giving width explicitly to the scroll view and its children. It is recommended to not use percentages for width and height for scrollview and its children when the horizontal property true.